# redirecting with javascript injected from code behind not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

this is the property which give me site root path

```
public static string SiteRootPath
    {
        get
        {
            string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            string appRootUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appRootUrl) || appRootUrl == "/")
            {
                return host + "/";
            }
            else
            {
                return host + appRootUrl + "/";
            }
        }
    }
```

i do like this

```
string path = EMS.DAL.DALHelper.SiteRootPath + "Home.aspx";
```

then i do this

```
string script = "<script language='javascript' >alert('User registered successfully');window.location.replace('" + path + "');</script>";
Page.RegisterStartupScript("alert", script);
```

This redirects me to home page and works perfectly fine on localhost but not on the IIS where the site is published.

when i check the page source only this is found "alert('User registered successfully');" inside script tags ??

Not able to solve it.

Any ideas ??

Comment: you can check the javascript code from the browser source and identify what exactly is passed to `window.location`

Comment: as i said just the alert('User registered successfully'); is found on page source, window.location nowhere !!

Comment: have you tried `window.location = '/';` instead of the `window.location.replace('" + path + "');`

Comment: would you mind telling what was the result when you *already did that*?

Comment: check my comment to Kjartan :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I to understand that this works correctly in IIS on your `localhost`? Did you perhaps have a previous version of this app with the `alert()`, but without the `window.location.replace()`?

Sounds to me as if the version of your application hosted on that site is not correct/updated, and that an outdated version is being shown. Otherwise, I can't see how just a part of your source is not being included.

I would try emptying any cache and temporary files (DLL's) relating to the application on the server, then clean, rebuild, and republish it.

Look for: folders called **`Temporary ASP.NET Files`** under places similar to the following, and empty them (while being careful not to delete anything other than the temporary-files, of course):

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
- (...)

Comment: Can i confess one thing that i had updated wrong server .. working fine